# How to allow null values for DevExpress Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, nullable

I use the Linq for getting data from database to Gridview. So, There are many Null Cells in my database but DevExpress Gridview does not display the null values.I upload 2 photos If you look at these understand easily what i want.

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56vUz.jpg)

[DevExpress Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FszuC.jpg)

it is my Linq Query for getting data from database.

```
var sorgu = from görevler in db.tbl_TaskOfProjects
                    join projeler in db.tbl_Projects
                    on görevler.project_id equals projeler.project_id
                    select new
                    {
                        görevler.p_task_id,
                        görevler.p_task_name,
                        görevler.p_task_start_date,
                        görevler.p_task_end_date,
                        görevler.p_task_status,
                        görevler.p_task_detail,
                        görevler.p_task_corporation,
                        projeler.project_id,
                        projeler.project_name
                    };
        gridGörevler.DataSource = sorgu;
```

Comment: Post any `GridView` usage details in your question. At this time it's still unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I expand the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in `GridView`, but in you query. You're performing `INNER JOIN` between tables `görevler` and `projeler` on column `project_id`, which is null. 
You have to make `LEFT JOIN`.

```
var sorgu = from görevler in db.tbl_TaskOfProjects
                join projeler in db.tbl_Projects
                on görevler.project_id equals projeler.project_id into groupProject // <-- changed from here down
                from project in groupProject.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    görevler.p_task_id,
                    görevler.p_task_name,
                    görevler.p_task_start_date,
                    görevler.p_task_end_date,
                    görevler.p_task_status,
                    görevler.p_task_detail,
                    görevler.p_task_corporation,
                    project.project_id,
                    project.project_name
                };
```

Comment: I did but it is still same. if project_id in task table is Null the gridview still does not display this row.

Comment: I find the solution. Your answer is correct but a little missing. Just i changed this : from project in groupProject.DefaultIfEmpty(). So it is done. Thanks for your answer.